# Why does my powershell script not wrap my path correctly?

Tags: windows, powershell

I've been tinkering with a Powershell script to automate some Streamlink stuff, and it's going okay, but I'm having an issue with the way streamlink is passing a command along, specifically with regards to wrapping the file path.

Here is the code (forgive the terrible formatting, I am not a pro, I'm only a beginner.)

```
Set-Location (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
$scriptdir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$streamurl = Read-Host -Prompt 'Stream URL'
$channel = youtube-dl --cookies $scriptdir\Resources\cookies.txt --write-description --skip-download -o "%(uploader)s" --get-filename $streamurl
if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $scriptdir\Recordings\$channel\)) {
    
    try {
        New-Item -Path $scriptdir\Recordings\$channel\ -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null #-Force
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error -Message "Unable to create directory '$channel'. Error was: $_" -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    "Successfully created directory '$channel'."

}
streamlink-auth $scriptdir\Resources\cookies.txt --retry-streams 10 -o "$scriptdir\Recordings\$channel\stream.mp4" $streamurl best
```

```
$scriptdir = Where the script is running
$streamurl = Self explanatory
$channel = the channel name of the stream
```

The issue I'm having is that when this command is passed along to streamlink, it seems to be wrapping wrong, as when streamlink tries to run the command, I get the following error:

```
streamlink args:  --retry-streams 10 -o W:\recordings\Recordings\【LIVE】新宿 大ガード交差点 Tokyo Shinjuku Live Ch\stream.mp4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQA5RcIZlAM best
usage: streamlink [OPTIONS] <URL> [STREAM]
streamlink: error: unrecognized arguments: Shinjuku Live Ch\stream.mp4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RQA5RcIZlAM best
```

Source:【LIVE】新宿 大ガード交差点 Tokyo Shinjuku Live Ch

I also tested this with a fully english channel (with the same script) and got the following:

```
streamlink args: --retry-streams 10 -o W:\recordings\Recordings\Watson Amelia Ch. hololive-EN\stream.mp4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeC6OHBRFTc best
usage: streamlink [OPTIONS] [STREAM]
streamlink: error: unrecognized arguments: hololive-EN\stream.mp4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeC6OHBRFTc best
```

Source: Watson Amelia Ch. hololive-EN

It seems that while the directory can be created fine, passing the variables into the streamlink command fails somewhere along the line. This *can* be worked around by simply moving into the channel directory with:

```
cd $scriptdir\Recordings\$channel\
```

and running the command without the extra variables in the path, but that's not the way I'd like to do it. I also want to add that youtube-dl has no issues with writing files to the directories created with this script as my postprocessing script writes files there without trouble, and powershell can still remove files there too.

I have asked the streamlink folks, and it's definitely not on their end, so obviously it's a powershell thing.

How do I solve this problem, because I am genuinely stumped now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm dumb.

Turns out when you pass something into a command, you have to pass it with Double quote, then single quote.

So instead of:

```
streamlink-auth $scriptdir\Resources\cookies.txt --retry-streams 10 -o "$scriptdir\Recordings\$channel\stream.mp4" $streamurl best
```

It needs to be:

```
streamlink-auth $scriptdir\Resources\cookies.txt --retry-streams 10 -o "'$scriptdir\Recordings\$channel\stream.mp4'" $streamurl best
```

Sorry for being the dum.